# Torus is 2-variety, proof of Hausdorff axiom

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification, algebraic-topology, proof-writing

I have to show that Torus defined as the quotient space obtained from the square $Q$ using the word $aba^{-1}b^{-1}$ to identificate the sides, is a topological 2-variety.

I've already proved that is locally 2-euclidean. Now I have to show that it is an Hausdorff space.

I want to use the following result.

**Theorem.** If $X$ is a compact and Hausdorff topological space and the quotient map $\pi:X\to X/_\sim$ is closed, then $X/_\sim$ is an Hausdorff space.

So, if $T$ is the torus, I have $T=\pi(Q)$ where $\pi:Q\to Q/_\sim=T$ is the quotient map. $Q$ is compact because it's closed and limited and it's Hausdorff because it is subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$ that it is Hausdorff. The only thing to prove is that $\pi$ is a closed map.

Let be $C$ a closed subset of $Q$. I have to show that $\pi^{-1}(\pi(C))$ is closed for all $C$ closed subset of $Q$.

Case $1:$

If $C\cap \bigcup_i L_i\ne \emptyset$, where $L_i$ is a side of $Q$, I think that $C$ is saturated, and so $\pi^{-1}(\pi(C))=C$.

Case $2:$

Let $V_i$ the vertices of $Q$. I define

$B_i=\begin{cases}\{V_i\}, & if & \pi(V_i)\in \pi(C) \\ \emptyset, & if & \pi(V_i)\notin \pi(C) \end{cases}$

If $L_i$ and $L_j$ are identificated, let $\varphi_{i,j}$ the homeomorfism between them.

$A_i=\begin{cases}\bigcup_j \varphi_{i,j} (C\cap L_j), & if & \pi(L_i)\cap \pi(C)=\emptyset \\ \emptyset, & if & \pi(L_i)\cap \pi(C)\ne \emptyset \end{cases}$.

With this definition, $A=\bigcup_i A_i$ is a closed subset of $Q$ because it is a finite union of closed sets; $B=\bigcup_i B_i$ is also closed for the same reason of $\bigcup_i A_i$.

So $\pi^{-1}(\pi(C))=C\cup A\cup B$ is closed.

So $\pi$ is a closed map and using the previous theorem, I have that $T$ is Hausdorff.

It is correct? Is there someone that help me to write more clearly this proof?

Comment: Do you mean for case 1 that $C \cap \bigcup_i L_i = \emptyset$?

Comment: What you call a $2$-variety is a **$2$-manifold**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proof looks correct (but please write out bounds on indices in the future: all your $i$'s and $j$'s start nowhere and end nowhere) to me, but I think you can "streamline" the whole thing a bit: For starters, note that $B$ (and thus the $B_i$'s) are superfluous since they are always going to be contained in one of the $A_i$. Also you don't have to treat case 1 separately, even if its short; it's covered by case 2 (and happens exactly when $A = \emptyset$), and the case distinction in the definition of the $A_i$ is also superfluous for a similar reason. With this in mind, how about something like the following (I'll also substitute some standard notation):

> Let $I^2 = [0, 1]^2$ be the square and let $L_1, \ldots, L_4 \subset \partial I^2$ be the four closed boundary line segments in clockwise order. Moreover, let $\varphi_i\colon L_i \overset{\cong}{\to} L_{i + 2}$ ($i = 1, 2$) be the linear homeomorphisms along which the $L_i$ are identified in the quotient. If $C \subseteq I^2$ is closed, then we have that $\pi^{-1}(\pi(C)) = C \cup B$ where $B = \pi^{-1}(\pi(C \cap \partial I^2))$, and by definition of the gluing relation we find that $B \cap L_i = (C \cap L_i) \cup \varphi_i^{-1}(C \cap L_{i + 2})$ ($i = 1, 2$) which is obviously closed, so $B = \bigcup_{i = 1}^4 (B \cap L_i)$ must be, too. Thus, $\pi^{-1}(\pi(C))$ is closed, whence $\pi$ is a closed map.

For completeness sake, I also want to mention that there's a better (in my opinion) proof that goes like this:

> Let $\psi\colon I^2 \to T = S^1 \times S^1$ be given by $\psi(x, y) = (e^{2i \pi x}, e^{2i \pi y})$. This is continuous (as you surely recall from analysis :), bijective when restricted to $I^2 \setminus \partial I^2$ and respects the gluing relation defining $I^2 / {{\sim}}$, so factors over the quotient to give a continuous **bijection** $I^2 / {{\sim}} \to T$; but since $I^2$ is compact and $T$ is Hausdorff, this bijection is automatically a homeomorphism. Thus, $I^2 / {{\sim}}$ is, like $T$, a manifold; in particular Hausdorff, second countable, locally Euclidean, ...

Which more or less avoids having to actually do any work :)